# Get SPWeb from SPContext in WCF hosted on SharePoint

Tags: 2010, development, wcf, spcontext

I have created and deployed a WCF service in SharePoint and I am sending requests using JQuery. Every thing is working fine except for sub sites.

Lets say I have these two service URLs:

```
 - http://localhost:1111/_vti_bin...../MethodName
 - http://localhost:1111/subsite/_vti_bin...../MethodName
```

When I use these two URLs the `SPContext.Current.Site` is the same and is correct.
But the `SPContext.Current.Web` is the same which is incorrect. Using the second URL the `SPWeb` object must be the sub web and not the root web.

How can I get the sub site as an `SPWeb` object? Do I need to always pass the web URL as a parameter to the WCF method?

Comment: Never worked with WCF Service in SP but sending the URL will definitely get the SPWeb object!

Comment: Yes I know but I am asking why the SPContext.Current.Web doesn't return the sub web and always the root web?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching I have concluded that the `SPContext.Current.Web` will always return the `RootWeb` so I need the URL of the specific sub web.

To avoid passing the SPWeb URL to every WCF method where I need an SPWeb object, I can do the following:

I am running my WCF service in ASP.NET comatibility mode so I can use the `HttpContext` object, and I can use `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl`. This property returns every thing in the URL string after the domain name. Then I can truncate this string to get the sub web relative URL and pass it to the `OpenWeb()` method.

*Example:*

At the client side the URL argument of the JQuery AJAX call is:

```
 http://localhost:1111/subsite/_vti_bin...../MethodName
```

On the server side if I use `HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl` I get:

```
/subsite/_vti_bin...../MethodName
```

Then after I truncate this string I pass the `/subsite` to the `OpenWeb()` method.

Any other ideas are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same case. But I took the Url from here:

```
Uri requestUri = System.ServiceModel.OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.To;
```

So I was able to create a SPSite object:

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(requestUri.Scheme + "://" + requestUri.Host)
{ 
    //your code
}
```